# Why is the makeCATdb function not working?

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am trying to do GO term enrichment analysis in R.  I followed this [tutorial](https://girke.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/GEN242/mydoc_systemPipeRNAseq_07.html).  When I get to this step...

```
catdb <- makeCATdb(myfile="data/GO/GOannotationsBiomart_mod.txt", lib=NULL, org="", colno=c(1,2,3), idconv=NULL)
```

...I get this error:

> Error in makeCATdb(myfile = "GOannotationsBiomark_mod.txt", lib = "NULL",  : 
>     could not find function "makeCATdb"

I tried installing systemPipeRdata and got the same error.  Please, how do I install this function?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  systemPipeR was not properly installed in RStudio.  For best results, please follow the instructions from the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/systemPipeR.html) website.

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly=TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("systemPipeR")
```